# symmetric tree algorithm (invert + same tree)

Tags: tree

Given a binary tree, check whether it is a mirror of itself (ie, symmetric around its center).

It is one question on Leetcode. What I do is to invert the tree and then compare whether the invert tree is the same as the original one. But I can't pass the test case. Mycode is as follows, Can someone give me any suggestion?  Thanks.

class Solution(object):

```
def isSymmetric(self, root):
    node = self.invert(root)
    def dfs(root, node):
        if not root and not node:
            return True
        if not root or not node:
            return False
        if root.val == node.val and dfs(root.left, node.left) and dfs(root.right, node.right):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    return dfs(root, node)


def invert(self, node):
    if node:
        node.left, node.right = self.invert(node.right), self.invert(node.left)
    return node
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like lot of work to invert and validate. You can try to print the tree and track return value on every step. My guess is it's running out of time as it has additional operations.

Or

You can recurse through the tree and check if left and right match for each node.

Example :

```
def isSymmetric(self, root)
    #single node or no node
    if root == null : 
        return false

    else :
        return dfs(root)

def dfs(root):
    #single node
    if(root.left == null and root.right == null):
        return true

    #both childs exist
    if(root.left != null and root.right != null):
        return (dfs(root.left) & dfs(root.right))

    #Asymmetric
    else :
        return false
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can understand your method but still have some problem with my method. Do you think my logic (first invert the tree and then compare the invert tree to the original one) is right?

Comment: you've to understand that Leetcode can fail test case even on timeout. Invert logic looks correct to me. Try to run it locally and print it to see the result.

Comment: It gave true for following tree. means dfs logic is wrong. It fails on first condition, as it returns always true if both nodes are not none : root = node(2)
root.left = node(3)
root.right = node(4)
root.left.left = node(5)

Comment: Accept the answer if you're satisfied. Thanks